# Discord.js - filter who has specific role in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I have an object. I want to make this object to show only those who have the role I have specified. The object gets the data from the "quick.db" module.
for exp my object like this =

```
var users = [
{ ID: 747374763, data: 45600},
{ ID: 1111....., data: 33333},
.........{ ID: 22222, data: 4444}
]
```

the object here shows all of the data I specified in the "quick.db" module. I just want to show the data of the people (IDs) who have the role I have specified. how can i do like that ?
also im get object like this

```
var users = db.all().filter(x => x.ID.startsWith(`totalMessage`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

okay i did with `filter()`

```
 let filter = users.filter(function(member) {
return message.guild.member(member.ID).roles.has("role id")
})
```